# Is using if/then in VIEWS a reasonable security practice?

Tags: ruby, security, if-statement, slim-lang

I'm guessing no. Here's the situation I have in mind:

```
form action='/12345/destroy', method='POST'
  - if @current_user.kind_of? Admin
    button
  - else
    span You cant do that
```

What's the better way to go about constructing a page like this? Create a controller for those "in charge" and have the buttons there? What if the admin chooses to disallow some users from using the delete button, are we back to square one? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your example is perfectly fine IMHO, but it really depends on your requirements. If you think that someday there will be the need for more kinds of users and you're afraid the views could get messy, I'd recommend looking into an ACL library. Alternatively you can always roll your own authorization layer.

Answer (score 0):

Your view is fine, but obviously, it is in no way secure. You have to check the privileges in your "controller" (if you have one) or in that request's receiving end.

Also, that logic will probably be used in more than one place. You might consider extracting it into a helper method.

```
form action='/12345/destroy', method='POST'
  = render_destroy_action_for @current_user
```

Once you have that logic hidden in a method, it will be easier to change later.